# c# object's mapper class location within solution - best practise

Tags: c#

My solution consist of several projects - one of them is `Project.DAL`, where all EF db entities are defined.
The second one is `Project.Models` that contains models classes used in business logic, which are quite similar to their respective `Project.DAL` classes.

Now, I am using a mapper class to map between DAL<->Models classes, and my question is where would be the most natural location of that kind of mappers - should it be `Project.Models` or maybe there should be another project created like `Project.ObjectMappers` and then should it be referenced where required?

Comment: Project.DAL would be better

Comment: Though this question is opinion-based, I would suggest you add it on your main project. The reason for this is that for some reason you may implement different mappers depending on your platform. Also, it will allow you to add mapping for your entities and the models defined on your main project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mappers know both Models and DAL projects. This means that they **definitely cannot be in the Model project** (Models shouldn't know that EF is the storage solution).

As pointed by John Ephraim Tugado in the comments, this is opinion based, but if you want mine I'd put them in a sub-folder in the DAL; after all this is heavily dependant on the DAL implementation and internal objects.